# Keep Receiving FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '' error when writing to a file in python

Tags: python

This has been bugging me now for a very long time. I understand this error if I was opening the file in read mode that did not exist, but when writing a file to the directory, this error seems nonsensical as clearly the file doesn't exist yet. This has happened to me on a number of projects and I can't seem to find a fix for it.

I will leave all my code for this below. It is just a simple email archive gui to store emails of people

Many thanks

```
from tkinter import *
import os

def add_email():
    name_write = name_input.get()
    email_write = email_input.get()

    with open(name_write, "w") as file:
        file.write(name_write + "\n")
        file.write(email_write)

    name_entry.delete(0, END)
    email_entry.delete(0, END)

def input_screen():
    global screen1
    global name_input
    global email_input
    global name_entry
    global email_entry
    screen1 = Tk()
    screen1.title("Email Archive")
    screen1.geometry("250x200")

    name_input = StringVar()
    email_input = StringVar()

    Label(screen1, text = "Name:", font = ("Calibri", 13)).grid(row = 0, column = 0)
    Label(screen1, text = "Email:", font = ("Calibri", 13)).grid(row = 1, column = 0)
    name_entry = Entry(screen1, font = ("Calibri", 12), textvariable = name_input)
    name_entry.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
    email_entry = Entry(screen1, font = ("Calibri", 12), textvariable = email_input)
    email_entry.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
    Label(screen1).grid(row = 2, column = 0)
    Button(screen1, text = "Submit", command = add_email).grid(row = 3, column = 1)
    Label(screen1, text = "Name:", font = ("Calibri", 12)).grid(row = 4, column = 0)
    Label(screen1, text = "Email Address:", font = ("Calibri", 12)).grid(row = 4, column = 1)

def login():
    username_login = username.get()

    all_files = os.listdir()
    if username_login in all_files:
        input_screen()
    else:
        print("Nope!")   

    username_entry.delete(0, END)    

def landing():
    global screen
    global username
    global username_entry
    screen = Tk()
    screen.title("")
    screen.geometry("300x175")

    username = StringVar()

    Label(screen, text = "Email Archive:", background = "grey", width = "300", height = "2", font = ("Calibri", 13)).pack()
    Label(screen, text = "Master Password:", font = ("Calibri", 12)).pack(pady = 10)
    username_entry = Entry(screen, font = ("Calibri", 12), textvariable = username, show = "*")
    username_entry.pack()
    Button(screen, text = "Enter", width = "8", command = login).pack(pady = 10)

    screen.mainloop()

landing()
```

Comment: I initially did that and the same thing came up. Deleted as I thought it might be different but the same error persisted. Should have added it back. Apologies for that. The os.getcwd command came back with the directory I wanted to initially put the text file into (this is a separate folder called Names, and I used the os.chdir() command and put the absolute path in there and still to no avail unfortunately.

Comment: Once I deleted the login page, it worked absolutely fine which I find even more bizarre. I still want that master password login page though.

Comment: @snakecharmerb I have updated the code now following your advice but I still receive the same issue. Very Frustrating as this has never happened to me before when I wrote programs similar to this one in the past.